# VBA (Word) How to insert a Page Break at Paragraph?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to insert a page break at a specific paragraph, but it always inserts the page break at the first line/paragraph of the document, I don't understand why. Any ideas?

```
With Word.ActiveDocument
    .Paragraphs(15).Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    .Paragraphs(15).Range.InsertBreak WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
    'or this way (Is there a differece): .Paragraphs(15).Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
End With
```

Thanks Julius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see something different: for me, it replaces the specified paragraph with the page break, as described in the Help topic.

In any case, the key to this is to work with a specific `Range` object. It's not possible to "collapse" the entire 15th paragraph - the method has no action. The paragraph `Range` needs to be assigned to an independent `Range` object, which *can* be collapsed, then the page break inserted at that `Range` object.

For example:

```
Sub TestInsertPageBreak()
    Dim paraRange As Word.Range

    With ActiveDocument
        Set paraRange = .Paragraphs(15).Range
        paraRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        paraRange.InsertBreak WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So, it didn't work for me with the range object, but if insert the break before I input my text and my pictures, it works. Although I don't understand the paragraph numbering: My ```paragraph(15)``` does not refer to the 15th paragraph in my document, at least if I let VBA count the paragraphs to that point, it says a different number.
However, the range object does provide some easy to the whole code! Thanks.

Comment: @Heka I'm not sure I understand parts of your comment, but... I took the `Paragraphs(15)` directly from the code in the question... I did test what I posted before copying it in, here, and it worked "as advertised", inserting the page break after the "target paragraph". Without seeing your document, I can't know what might influence the paragraph count. But if there's a table, every cell in the table will be counted as (at least) one paragraph...

Comment: I am not sure either, what this "influence" is. I can post the things I did later. Your code works (that's why I marked it as solution), but not if I insert pictures before inserting the page break.
I will edit the original post later!

Comment: @Heka Pictures? Ah... If that's an issue, please compose the exact case as a NEW question, with steps to reproduce what you're doing. VERY IMPORTANT include whether the pictures are in-line with the text (`InlineShape` objects) or have text wrap formatting (`Shape`) objects as that influences how the code has to work. Screen shots with the desired result and what the code actually does would be helpful, as well.